# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:) for Azure Universal Package Build Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm getting `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)` while publishing Azure Universal Package via build pipelines.

```
Publishing package: app-service, version: 1.0.0.$(Rev:r) using feed id: ext-dep, project: null
E:\VSTSbuilds\Agent1\_work\_tool\artifacttool\0.2.189\x64\ArtifactTool.exe universal publish --feed ext-dep --service https://dev.azure.com/devops-project --package-name app-service --package-version 1.0.0.$(Rev:r) --path E:\VSTSbuilds\Agent1\_work\49\a --patvar UNIVERSAL_PUBLISH_PAT --verbosity None --description ""
{"@t":"2021-06-02T20:37:45.3431236Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 11235e34-d8e6-4f4a-ada6-345938e5967d","@i":"08e1e0b2","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-06-02 20:37:45.343Z"}
{"@t":"2021-06-02T20:37:45.4439750Z","@m":"Ensuring that the package does not yet exist...","@i":"40e01e14","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-06-02 20:37:45.443Z"}
{"@t":"2021-06-02T20:37:45.7865414Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender did not correlate any events with X-TFS-Session 11235e34-d8e6-4f4a-ada6-345938e5967d","@i":"2cdc2942","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-06-02 20:37:45.786Z"}
{"@t":"2021-06-02T20:37:45.7875769Z","@m":"An error occurred on the service. A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).","@i":"03bd9f62","@l":"Error","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Program","UtcTimestamp":"2021-06-02 20:37:45.787Z"}
##[error]Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to push the package. Exit code(1) and error({"@t":"2021-06-02T20:37:45.3431236Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 11235e34-d8e6-4f4a-ada6-345938e5967d","@i":"08e1e0b2","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-06-02 20:37:45.343Z"}
{"@t":"2021-06-02T20:37:45.4439750Z","@m":"Ensuring that the package does not yet exist...","@i":"40e01e14","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-06-02 20:37:45.443Z"}
{"@t":"2021-06-02T20:37:45.7865414Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender did not correlate any events with X-TFS-Session 11235e34-d8e6-4f4a-ada6-345938e5967d","@i":"2cdc2942","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-06-02 20:37:45.786Z"}
{"@t":"2021-06-02T20:37:45.7875769Z","@m":"An error occurred on the service. A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).","@i":"03bd9f62","@l":"Error","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Program","UtcTimestamp":"2021-06-02 20:37:45.787Z"})
##[error]Packages failed to publish
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a run number wasn't expanded and you got `:` in the package version:

```
--package-version 1.0.0.$(Rev:r)
```

This could be because of the missing dot (`.`) before `r`. Try this in your template:

```
1.0.0.$(Rev:.r)
```

See [Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number) for details.

Comment: 1.0.0.$(Rev:.r) did not resolved the issue but I hardcode it and it worked. After first success, I changed from custom to next patch so it took next patch version and will continue.